# What does it mean when we say circle is passing through origin?

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

i can imagine a line passing through the origin in infinite ways but circle is not a line and i am unable to picture it in my brain. i mean its a round figure not a line and its centre can be anywhere near the origin so what does it actually mean? does it touch both the coordinate axis? which should mean origin (0, 0) is inside the circle? in most websites and books they just start solving a problem when it touches x or y but dont clear this.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what your problem is. You have no trouble imagining a straight line passing through the origin, but you can't imagine a curve passing through the origin? What if the curve is only slightly curved, so it's almost straight, can you see it then?

Comment: you can say that because you already know the concepts clearly unlike someone who is learning.

Comment: This seems like a problem of terminology. Maybe you're confusing the word  “circle” (a curve) with “[disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics))” (the region bounded by a circle)?

Answer (score 1):

A circle passing through the origin means that the origin, i.e., the point $(0,0)$, lies on the circle.

In other words, $(0,0)$ satisfies the equation of the circle.

Comment: where on the circle? inside or on boundary?

Comment: @MohitSaxena On the circle, so on the "boundary". The circle itself is the "boundary". You can have a given point to be either outside, inside, or on the circle.

Comment: oh. so it will cut one axis at 0 and the other at some point and the distance from that point to the origin will be its diameter?

Comment: @MohitSaxena No, the line segment joining the two points of intersection on the axis, one being the origin, is in general a chord. Just having a circle passing through the origin gives you no information about the diameter or its centre

Answer (score 0):

Take a circle. Now mark a point $P$  on its circumference. It is a circle passing through the point $P$. If that point $P$ can be chosen to be origin, well and good. Now take any point on the plane. Let its distance from origin be $r$ units.  With that point as centre a circle of radius $r$ will be passing through origin.